# Cannot copy files from host to container in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm attempting to build a customer Alpine docker container and would like to copy some files from the host to the container. I understand that a number of questions have been asked on this but nothing seems to be working.

I have the following directory structure:

```
|- Docker
|---- Dockerfile
|---- default.conf
|---- nginx.conf
|---- php-fpm.conf
|---- www.conf
```

Then in my `Dockerfile`, I have the following:

```
COPY php-fpm.conf /etc/php8/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/
COPY www.conf /etc/php8/php-fpm.d/
```

Within the `Docker/` directory, I run: `Get-Content Dockerfile | docker build  -` and it outputs the following:

```
 => ERROR [19/24] COPY php-fpm.conf /etc/php8/                                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [20/24] COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [21/24] COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [22/24] COPY www.conf /etc/php8/php-fpm.d/                                                               0.0s
------
 > [19/24] COPY php-fpm.conf /etc/php8/:
------
------
 > [20/24] COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/:
------
------
 > [21/24] COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/http.d/:
------
------
 > [22/24] COPY www.conf /etc/php8/php-fpm.d/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/www.conf" not found: not found
```

I'm not sure what is meant by `failed to compute cache key`

Comment: Is there any reason you're piping your Dockerfile to docker? This will build your container _without context_.

Comment: Yep doing a `docker build .` worked

Comment: Add copy with ./ . Example  COPY ./php-fpm.conf /etc/php8/. "./" mean current directory. Do check the .dockerignore file too.